# Initializing a certain struct field on-initialization in C

Tags: c, string, struct

What I would like to do here is initializing all the players' names with the empty string value `""`, I have heard it can be done at the declaration point in C99, but I'm not entirely sure how.

```
typedef struct data_players
{   char name[25];
    int hp;
    int mana;
    int id;

}player;

player player_list[10]
```

In this case how should I proceed?

Comment: You are editing the question, making answers invalid. Not a good thing to do here.

Comment: I know, I forgot an rather important aspect of the question, apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At declaration time, you initialize structs with `{}` like this:

```
player player_list[10] = {{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0},{"", 0, 0, 0}};
```

Note that any skipped initializers will default to zero, so if you are always initializing the entire array to zero, this will suffice:

```
player player_list[10] = {0};
```

---

Also note that if `player_list` is a global or a static variable, it will automatically be initialized to all zeroes. As if you called

```
memset(player_list, 0, sizeof(player_list));
```

at program start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this did solve my problem, since it dosn't really matter if I initialize everything to zero, in my case.

Comment: `player player_list[10] = {};` is using a GNU C extension. `{0}` is the ISO C way.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct data_players
{   char name[25];

} player = "";
```

or

```
struct data_players
{   char name[25];

} player = { "" };
```

---

This initializes the first member of the structure at declaration time. If there are more members, separate them with comma.
One more thing. Your struct should not be type-defined at declaration time to do that kind of initialization.

---

if you have an array of structures and you want to initialize them in C99 you can use "designated initializer" at declaration time.

```
player arr [2] = { {.name = ""}, {.name = ""} };
```

This will initialize `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`'s name members to a null string. Though I see not much sense in it as it defaults to a null string anyway.

Comment: Hm, perhaps my example wasn't that good, because there are multiple fields in the struct, not only the name, in that case, how would that be? sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Zetsuno I see now you've accepted mtijanic's offering. Good thing it helped.. though his solution is not C99 specific but C89 specific. The designated initializer I provided not only is C99 specific but also a better way of initialization (: Take this into a consideration.